# Rotation animation not working properly after using submitList from ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, listadapter, expandablelistadapter

In my project I have an expandable recycler view. Almost everything is working properly.

When I expand the view I have a chevron, that I want to perform a 180º rotation and vice versa for the collapsing animation.

I'm using this function to do the rotation `view.animate().rotation(180f)` for one of the states and for the other I pass `0` to the `rotation` function.

The icon is rotated the first time **with** the animation. My problem now is that, the second time I call `submitList(List<UIModel>)` it doesn't perform the animation itself, but the icon blinks into the 180º state.

One important note is that I'm using MVI, and I added a click listener to the `ViewHolder`, which is simply a callback for the `Fragment`, that will pass this info to the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` will update its state to have that list item as expanded and then submit the list.

Rotation animation works perfectly, if I call the function mentioned above right in the click listener, without calling the `submitList()` function.

As a summary, this is flow (first time 8th step doesn't apply, and it works properly with the animation):

1. User clicks on chevron;
2. callback is called;
3. fragment notifies view model;
4. view model updates state;
5. fragment is notified that there are changes;
6. fragment submits list calling (`submitList()`);
7. `onBindViewHolder` is called, and I perform the rotation animation according to the UIModel `isExpanded` variable.
8. rotation is applied, but without any animation, just a flick between both position

Answer (score 0):

Two *wild guesses*:

1. Is the rotation value part of the `DiffUtil.Callback`? (the value or something to indicate that the item changed).
2. Did you try *for the sake of Android* to replace `view.animate().rotation(180f)` with something more silly like:

```
view.post( ... )
```

This would perform your animation inside the *next* rendering frame; I have a suspicion the animation is getting buried there and the final state is shown (the thing rotated already).

Comment: 1. Yes, I mean, it's part of the model that's references by DiffUtil;
2. Not yet, will try it now and will update the comment

Comment: Had no luck by using `view.post( ... )` as you suggested

Comment: I have the similar feeling regarding the animation getting buried, because if I just perform the animation without calling `submitList()` again, the animation works fine.

Comment: Just for "fun", try `postDelayed` and add an absolutely-arbitrary number like 250 (ms) and see if the animation is performed afterwards.

Comment: Curious... First time it performs the animation considering the delay. The second and following times, it doesn't do either

Comment: This could be due to the fact that the view animation you're using, doesn't really modify the view, but only where the view is drawn. I would perhaps try to use a Property Animation via a [value animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator) or [object animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator).  Take a look at the [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) docs for more info, perhaps this works better in your case.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that fact regarding modifying the view, really need to get more practice with this. I ended up using `RotateAnimation` with `fillEnabled` and `fillAfter` flags set to true and it worked really great. 

Should I be using one of those you referred anyway? Do you have any opinion on this?

Comment: Yeah, Android Animation has gone through "changes" throughout the years so you're not alone. If a RotateAnimation works (with the fill flags) then you're good to go. No need to bother with the other things unless you have issues. _if it ain't broken, don't fix it_ :) I do, however, recommend you peek at the Animators, since they are relatively easy to use and quite handy (notably the ObjectAnimator, where you could pass `rotation` as the value, since it would internally call `setRotation(...)`). But if it works, enjoy :)